# Link library name for JVM TI

Tags: java, gcc, jvmti

I am trying to write a JVM TI sample agent on Mac OS X. I have Java 5 installed. I want to know against which dynamic library should I link my sample agent code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to link against anything.

```
gcc -I/path/to/java/include -shared -fPIC -o libagent.so agent.c
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `libjvm.so` on Linux, so I suspect something similar on the Mac.